# Web-bluetooth does not discover any BLE devices on mac

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, google-chrome-devtools, web-bluetooth

This seems an easy issue to solve, but I really could not find any good answer for the past 10h.

According [to browser and platform implementation status for Web-bluetooth](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md), I should be able to pair BLE devices using Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.101) on a MacBook Pro 2011.

I use a BLE Peripheral Simulator App and I can pair it with other devices. However, I cannot pair it using Chrome on Mac as it does not find any devices (I use this [demo](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/demos/tree/gh-pages/heart-rate-sensor) for testing).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. It turns out that my Mac (from 2011) is not ready for BLE.

1. Click the  menu.
2. Select About This Mac.
3. Click on the More Info... button.
4. Click on the System Report... button.
5. Select Bluetooth from the sidebar on the left, underneath "Hardware." Scan down the list of information until you find "LMP Version."

If your Mac is equipped with BLE, LMP Version will say 0x6. My LMP Version is 0x4.

Comment: Indeed. See macOS notes at https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#notes